# How can verify if a date is in the format dd mon ' yy in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a column full of dates in the format `dd mon 'yy` (Ex: `20 Jan '16`). How can I verify that each date value in the column has this same format in Ruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Date.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) which fails with an exception when it cannot parse the date:

```
require 'date'

Date.strptime("20 Jan '16", "%d %b '%y")
#=> <Date: 2016-01-20 ((2457408j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

Date.strptime("31 Feb '16", "%d %b '%y")
#=> ArgumentError: invalid date
```